# How can I add value to a row?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a class record. I created a table, with column of names and activities.

the table looks like this.

```
Name   |    Q1    |    Q2      |
--------------------------------
Prinz  |    20    | (input text)
```

My aim is to save the input data into my database, but I need to have the id of the student(Prinz). I already managed to save the grade but want the id of that particular student to be save as well. My MYSQL table has 4 att. namely, grade_id(auto_inc), stud_id, grade and the activity type(Quiz, Assignment, Exam).

Here's my code

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 845px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 65px;">
            <tr style="background-color: #caccca; text-align: center;">
            <td style="width: 130px;" class="td-1">NAME</td>
            <?php 
            $result = mysql_query("select * from subject_grade ");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
            $act_type = $row->act_type;
            echo '<td style="width: 130px;" class="td-1">'.$row->act_type .'</td>';
            }
            ?>
            <td class="td-1">GPA</td>
            </tr>
            <?php 

            $result = mysql_query("select * from student_db ");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
            echo '<tr class="border" style="background-color: #f9f9f9;"><td style="width: 150px;" class="td-2" name="student"><p>'.$row->firstname .' '. $row -> lastname .'</p></td>';

                $id = $row->student_id;
                for ($i=0; $i<$numrows; $i++){
                    echo '<form action ="record.php" method="POST"><td style="text-align: center;"><input type="text "style="font-size: 12px; width: 20px;" name="grade"><input style="display: none;" type="text" name="id" value="'.$id.'"><input type="submit"></td></form>';
                }
            echo '<td style="width: 80px;"class="td-2"></td>';
            }

            ?>

            </tr>
        </table>
```

RECORD.PHP File

```
if($_POST['grade']){
        $sql="INSERT INTO class_record (grade, student_id)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[grade]','$_POST[id]')";

        $rs1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        echo $_POST['grade'] .' '. $studID;

} else echo 'ERROR';
```

?>

I hope you can help me, this is for our school project.

Comment: It is yet unclear to me, what you are trying to achieve and what problem you are facing (i.e. what should happen vs what does actually happen).

Comment: I want to create a class record using a table. In a table, I have an input area each cell. And once I add an input, it will automatically be save to my database with values student ID, grade and activity type. And the cell will now be updated to the grade entered. I hope that's clear.

Answer (score 0):

please change your query, you have an error in you query ,
change

```
$sql="INSERT INTO class_record (grade, student_id)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[grade]','$_POST[id]')";
```

with

```
$sql="INSERT INTO class_record (grade, student_id)
        VALUES
        ('".$_POST['grade']."','".$_POST['id']."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query,

$sql="INSERT INTO class_record (grade, student_id)
        VALUES
        ('".$_POST['grade']."','".$_POST['id']."')";